# Date conversion in JSP via JSTL from XMLCalendar to util date

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I am trying to convert XMLCalendar date to normal date format for rendering on JSP page. While using below tag I am getting exception:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${xmlCalendarDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

with this tag i am getting exception as

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert 2015-07-02T21:33:35Z of type class org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type.internal.XMLCalendar to class java.util.Date
```

Is there any other tag or other approach to render this date on my JSP page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <td data-title="Order Date">
        <fmt:formatDate value="${order.dateCreated.toGregorianCalendar().time}" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" />
        <%--${order.dateCreated}--%>
    </td>
    <!--order status-->
    <td data-title="Order Status">
        <c:if test="${order.status.code=='CREATED'}">
            <spring:message code="web.page.order.create" />
        </c:if>
    </td>
    <%-- ${order.status.code}</td>--%>
    <!--quanity-->
    <td data-title="Total"><span class="f_size_large fw_medium scheme_color">${order.currency.symbol}${order.totalChargeAmount.price}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a subclass of [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html). You can get a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) out of it by first obtaining the [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) via [`XMLGregorianCalendar#toGregorianCalendar()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toGregorianCalendar--) and then calling [`Calendar#getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--) on it.

So, assuming an EL 2.2 capable environment, this should do:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${xmlCalendarDate.toGregorianCalendar().time}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

If you're not on EL 2.2 yet (which is standard part of Servlet 3.0 / Java EE 6), then you'd need to perform the `XMLGregorianCalendar` to `Date` conversion in the front controller first.

```
Date date = xmlCalendarDate.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
// ...
```